# How to get Data from REDIS in Spring Boot based on multiple parameter in where clause like we get in JPA as findByIdAndName

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, redis

I have a requirement where I need to replace mysql with Redis, so I have method for mysql in JPA as findByIdAndName.
And in Redis I am  storing key and Object like <Integer,Employee> (Employee is a class and Integer is Id ) so If I want to get employee object from redis based on Integer-Id I can easily get those with findById mentioned below but what if I want to get data based on Employee Name and age so any Idea how to use hashOperation in that way or how to store data in redis in way so that I can get the desired result.

***For Example in RedisImplementation:***

```
 public Employee findById(Integer id) {
                    Employee emp = redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("EMPLOYEE_HASH",Id);          
        }
```

I want to add a method which can get data based on ID and Name like findByIdAndName

Answer (score 1):

You should use @Cacheable as it enables you to define key with EL expressions.

An example is the following :

```
@Cacheable(value = "items", key = "#id")
public Item getItem(Integer id) {
    Item item = itemRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    logger.info("Loading data from DB {}", item);
    return item;
}
```

I am pretty sure @Cacheable supports composite keys like POJOS instead of primitives as keys. Also if you do not specify key explicitly it will take the arguments of the method that has the annotation as a key.

A really good documentation / tutorial is the following one https://springhow.com/spring-boot-redis-cache/

Hope I helped :)

Comment: I am using redis as a database so I dont want to use these annotations is there any way similar to findById so that we can use findByIdAndName ?

Comment: I think this annotation can be used for both a non ephemeral and an ephemeral redis (a non ephemeral redis is like a db). If you need to use it as an actual db then I am sorry i've never done that :(

Comment: I am using this @Cacheable(value = "items", key = "#id") at method level but my logger.info is getting printed even for the same Integer id

Comment: I think you need to check what's going on with the TTL in cache (time to live). This need to be configured (also you can check from the redis cli the statistics , if caches are getting populated etc).

Comment: Yes I have added TTL in application.properties. One thing I want to ask that is it important to use @Cacheable at the controller ? because if I am using it at controller just below the get API it is working fine but in service class at method level it is not working